# RRAS DNS Entries from Windows Vista / 7 Clients

Tags: domain-name-system, rras

How do I stop a Win 2003 RRAS server from sending it's own DNS info to the VPN Client?

We have RRAS running on Win 2003 Server.  The server has a fixed IP, but the RRAS is setup to use DHCP for assigning VPN client IPs.

Our DHCP is setup to send 4 DNS server entries in this order:

- Internal DNS Server
- Backup Internal DNS Server
- External DNS Server
- Backup External DNS Server

Here's the thing: the RRAS server seems to automatically send it's own DNS entries (from it's NICs) to the client first, and then the entries from DCHP are applied.  But since the RRAS server has Internal DNS and Backup Internal DNS as it's own DNS entries, it sends these first, and when the DCHP DNS entries come down, only the ones not already added get added (just the externals).  This results in the following DNS list on the VPN client:

- External DNS Server
- Backup External DNS Server
- Internal DNS Server
- Backup Internal DNS Server

This is no good of course, because internal names will no longer resolve.

How do I stop the RRAS server from sending it's own DNS info to the VPN Client?

Note this doesn't seem to happen on WinXP - it gets the DNS servers direct from the DHCP in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the [opposite problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/139743/dynamic-dns-registration-for-vpn-clients). My RRAS server refuses to send the DNS (DHCP lease options) info to my clients....

Answer (score 0):

The RRAS server will send its primary and secondary DNS servers as part of the [PPP negotiation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200211/). I don't think you can stop this. The DHCPInform info should over-ride this when sent, the fact that it doesn't when there are duplicated addresses seems like a bug.

There's a lot of useful info on this in the MS KB article [Understanding DHCP IP Address Assignment for RAS Clients](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160699/)