# When connected to Windows VPN (RRAS) I'm able to ping by FQDN but not Hostname

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rras

I'm sure there must be some sort of setting that I need to change but I'm not sure what it is.

The VPN clients are using their local gateway and not the remote gateway.

For instance:

I can connect to server.domain.local but when I try to connect to server it will instead try to connect to server.comcast.net instead of server.domain.local.

I know that I can manually add in the DNS suffix that it should first try to connect to, but that doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Can anybody lend a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are the clients running?

Comment: Windows XP Pro SP3 is the one that I'm currently troubleshooting with. My Windows 7 laptop isn't having the issue but I think that is because my laptop is already joined to the domain so it already appends the DNS suffixes, but it could be a different reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the clients are using the right DNS server - it sounds as though they're using the ISP's DNS server in preference to your gateway's.

It's possible you're seeing the same problem as experienced in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/79678/rras-dns-entries-from-windows-vista-7-clients)

Run the command *nslookup* from the command line on one of your clients while it is connected to the VPN and check what your default DNS server is. You can also test resolving various server and FQDNs once you've done this. Post the output.

Comment: nslookup says the default server name is unknown but it shows the proper IP for the default DNS server. Why would that happen?

Comment: This is not necessarily indicative of a problem, it probably just means Reverse DNS lookup isn't setup on the DNS server, so you can't get its name from its IP. This shouldn't impact on your ability to resolve IPs from FQDNs using the server. You may want to restup a reverse lookup zone on the DNS server, but it's not super important.

Did you try resolving the local address in nslookup? Did it resolve to the correct IP?